# Text editor saving unspecified html tags which disturbs website's contents

Tags: html, asp.net, text-editor

I am using a text editor from where user can upload articles on my site in my ASP.net application. The problem i am facing is that if the author copy some html text and paste it in that editor and saves it, it disturbs the whole content of site when i load these list of articles on my home page. According to my analysis this problem is occurring due to unspecified tags(some divs might be opening or closing at wrong places). How can i overcome this problem? Is there any way to eliminate these irrelevant tags?

Comment: You'll need to strip all formatting on paste.

Comment: And what are you doing when the user pastes `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of encoding and decoding. You will need to do this.

[htmlencode-htmldecode](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode)